# Eloquent many to many relationship without middle table

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm new to Eloquent and struggling mightily with the following.

In my database (mysql 5.7), there are 2 tables and structured as below.

article:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    title: "xxx",
    content: "xxx",
    tag_ids: [
        4,
        5
    ]
}
```

tag:

```
{
    _id: 4,
    tag: "tag1"
}
```

In ArticleModel, has a cast

```
protected $casts = [
    "tags" => "array"
];
```

It is possible to make a many to many relationship without a middle table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: many to many relationship requires another table so that it can map the relation between entity A and entity B

Comment: For existing data, I would recommend to migrate the data into a new pivot table called `article_tag` with one or two clever queries, then setup the relations in Laravel as intended

Comment: Ok, it is possible to avoid pivot table?

Comment: No it's not possible. Just create the join table.

Answer (score 0):

I created a package with JSON relationships: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

You can create a many-to-many relationship like this:

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = [
       'tag_ids' => 'array'
    ];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToJson(Tag::class, 'tag_ids');
    }
}

class Tag extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function articles()
    {
       return $this->hasManyJson(Article::class, 'tag_ids');
    }
}
```